# How to write base64 to model's FileField?

Tags: javascript, python, base64

On client I convert file to base64 via `.readAsDataURL(f)` function and send it in json by sockets.
On server side I use this code:

```
AttachedFile.objects.create(file=ContentFile(b64decode(b64string), filename))
```

When I send .txt files all going right, but when I upload images by this way, after opening I get "Image is corrupted" message. Where I am wrong?

Comment: I think the `b64string` gets corrupted once it reaches the `ContentFile`. Cause that line of code seems correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need use secont part of base64.split('base64,'):

```
AttachedFile.objects.create(message=cm, file=ContentFile(b64decode(value.split('base64,')[1]), key))
```